# JQuery Animation stutter in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, animation

I am currently making my first website and I'm using JQuery for the animations. The animation is very smooth in IE but in Firefox, it stutters severely. The website is [www.chiahaoyang.com](http://www.chiahaoyang.com). I've spent countless hours trying to fix it to no availability. Thanks!

**UPDATE1**: The JQuery loading/animation code is:

```
    function ajaxLoad(input){
        contentBox.fadeIn();
        content.fadeOut("medium",function() {
            content.load("ajax_pages/"+input+".html", function(){
                var contentHeight = content.height();
                if(contentHeight > screen.height*0.66){
                    contentBox.animate({height: screen.height*0.66},"slow",function(){
                        content.delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
                    });
                } else {
                    contentBox.animate({height: contentHeight},"slow",function(){
                        content.delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
                    });             
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

content is the div that I load ajax pages to. contentBox is the div enclosing content

**UPDATE 2**: The source of the choppiness is some css3 properties:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);  
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
```

It makes sense that these enhancements put more load on the browser, but are there any ways to get around it to make Firefox render it just as smoothly as IE?

**UPDATE 3**: Okay I just replaced the above code with:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); 
box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
```

Now it's a lot smoother...

Comment: I think this has something to do with the computer's graphic card and processing power, plus how the browser render the page.

Comment: I've clicked on "resume" and it took 6.21s to perform the GET... You need to improve your method to show contents!

Comment: @nhahtdh I highly doubt that is the issue. The animation is very smooth in IE but not Firefox.

Comment: @Zuul The resume content is actually all handled by scribd...I am considering changing it though.

Comment: @DannyYang: Depending on how the browser is optimized, the performance (and memory usage) can be different.

Comment: You website looks all bunched up on my screen. try scaling it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the specific code in question so we dont have to search your site for it.

Comment: @DannyYang, check [this Link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/76169930/stackoverflow/question/10771131/chiahaoyang_com_onload.jpg) to view some problems that may cause performance issues... Notice the 404!?

Comment: I just went to www.chiahaoyang.com and all the animation runs very smooth in Firefox 12.0???

Comment: @AdamSack If the sidebar icons are stacking up, it should be fixed now.

Comment: @Zuul I was uploading some files and forgot to take those two lines out, they are now out. But I don't think that's the problem since those two are only there because I was trying to find alternative ways to fix it, which failed.

Comment: @killerbunnyattack Really? Try clicking on any links in Firefox and IE and compare. For me I could see a big difference in terms of smoothness

Comment: Ya, I see it now. It was a lot smoother on my first visit.

Answer (score 1):

this issue is very annoying for me, I'm designing my site as well and I have to lower the box-shadow effects for firefox to run it decently, not to mention jquery elements... those can't even run if there are too much box-shadow effects. I dont get why this isn't happening if I use IE, my site run smooth as water on it. obviously there is something going on here, please someone give us some help :) thanks.